# Blazor and Webdriver

Tags: c#, selenium, unit-testing, blazor

Is it possible to test Blazor UI with Selenium?

I added an id in the counter page, and tried to find the element by its id, in a test.
What am I missing?
The results are always empty, Title and PageSource are also empty. The navigation works, it opens the correct url.

The project is a Blazor project, 3.0, with MS core test project, and some fragments are already in RCL.

[Dependencies of MS Test Project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DWeCp.png)

```
[TestInitialize]
        public void MyTestInitializeT()
        {
            _driver = new ChromeDriver();
        }

   [TestMethod]
        public void FindElementInCounterTest()
        {
            _driver.Navigate()
                .GoToUrl("https://localhost:5001/counter");

            WaitXseconds();

            var res = _driver.FindElement(By.Id("counter100"));
            //.SendKeys("");

            //Assert.AreEqual("Options", _driver.Title);
        }
```

Comment: Is that Id visible in the page?

Comment: Q: *"Is it possible?"* A: Yes. Do you have an id named `counter100`? What does your Razor view look like? Do you get a specific exception when you call `FindElement`?

Comment: Got it. I increased the waiting time, it know finds the elements.

Answer (score 0):

The view:

```
<title>This is a title.</title>
<h1 id="counter100" class="counter100">Counter</h1>
```

The test was running before the page was being loaded. I am now getting some feedback.
The title can be found btw, but its value cannot be checked, because it is not visible in this template.
Ty4the help.

```
//Test:
[TestMethod]
        public void FindElementInCounterTest()
        {
            _driver.Navigate()
                .GoToUrl("https://localhost:5001/counter");

            WaitXseconds(10000); // wait 10 secs

            var res = _driver.FindElement(By.Id("counter100"));
            var res2 = _driver.FindElement(By.TagName("h1"));
            var res3 = _driver.FindElement(By.TagName("title"));
            Assert.AreEqual(true, res.Displayed);
            Assert.AreEqual("Counter", res.Text);
            Assert.AreEqual(true, res2.Displayed);
            Assert.AreEqual("Counter", res2.Text);
            Assert.AreEqual(false, res3.Displayed);
            Assert.AreEqual("", res3.Text);//Assert.AreEqual("This is a title.", res3.Text);

            //.SendKeys("");

            Assert.AreEqual(false, string.IsNullOrEmpty(_driver.Title));
            Assert.AreEqual(false, string.IsNullOrEmpty(_driver.PageSource));
        }
```